# Different between Location and Geopoint in Android

Tags: android, location

Can anyone tell me whats the different is between Location and Geopoint in Android.

It seems that both is a Location with longitude and latitude.

Regards jakob

Answer (score 2):

They're different classes.  Location is used by the base Android gps and network location API.  Geopoint is used by Google Maps.  They both encapsulate the same idea (a location in latitude and logitude) but have a different api and are used by different libraries.

Comment: Other way around-  you have to use geopoint with google maps.  Of course its pretty easy to write a function to convert one to the other as needed.